# Servlet + Jsp Issue

Tags: html, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a JSP page, from where onClick I want to execute a servlet page. Can anybody help me, how can it possible ?

Comment: On a click of what? What do you want to happen after the click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" id="click" name="click"/>

if(request.getParameter("click")!=null)
{
    request.sendRedirect("URL");
}
```

or

```
public class Dispatcher extends HttpServlet 
{
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
    {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
        request.getRequestDispatcher("URL");
        if (dispatcher != null) dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Google search for the difference between `request.sendRedirect("URL");` and `request.getRequestDispatcher("URL");`

Comment: Thanks. But, I have @WebServlet(name="x", urlPatterns={"/xx"}).Among them which I have to use as URL value ?

Comment: Array of url patterns for which the sevlet should be invoked - Atlease one url pattern is requried such as `@WebServlet(asyncSupported = false, name = "HelloAnnotationServlet", urlPatterns = {"/helloanno"},
initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="param1", value="value1"), @WebInitParam(name="param2", value="value2")}
)`

Comment: The urlPatterns or the value attribute on the annotation MUST be present. It is recommended to use value when the only attribute on the annotation is the url pattern and to use the urlPatterns attribute when the other attributes are also used. It is illegal to have both value and urlPatterns attribute used together on the same annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You need a form with single button, and send form to the servlet

or you can use simple `<a href="yourServlet">some text to be clicked</a>` or link under image

your Servlet must be described in web.xml or by annotation to let it be called.

Comment: Thanks. But, I have @WebServlet(name="x", urlPatterns={"/xx"}).Among them which I have to use as href value ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an AJAX call to invoke the servlet if you don't want to reload the current page or perform a redirect using the `window.location.href` property. If you want to send some values to the server you could send them in the AJAX request body or as query string parameters if you decide to redirect.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method=GET action="servlet/nextPage">
some text here
<input type=submit>
</form>
```